# Display static html file on /register

Tags: nginx

I have a web app (boilerplated with VueJS CLI) running on nginx.

All requests to this app (except `/api`) are handled by root `index.html` (since it's using frontend-side routing). I want add another exception to this rule, so that when we go to `/register` it redirects us to some other static public html file (not related with this VueJS app, but sitting under the same project/directory).

In other words, **I want to redirect `/register` to `/public/xyz/index.html` but without changing the URL displayed in the browser address bar**.

I tried to add `location = /register` rule but it doesn't seem to work, on `/register` it still keeps redirecting me to `/app/dist/index.html`.

My nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /app/dist;
    index index.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location = /register {
        root /public/xyz;
        index index.html
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        expires 0;
    }
    location ~ ^/api/(.*) {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_pass_request_headers on;

          proxy_pass <ENV_API_URL>/$1$is_args$args;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use an `alias` instead, to substitute directly for the path you want.

```
location = /register {
    alias /public/xyz/index.html;
}
```